# FFMpeg won't encode to Webm when adding a watermark using -vf

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I am successfully adding an overlay with x264 and -vf with this command:

WORKING x264 ENCODE WITH WATERMARK:

```
ffmpeg -i /private/youtube/$i -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -vf 'movie=/user_ftp/1037/watermarks/w640X360.png [logo];[in][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]' -crf 24 -ab 160k -s 640x360 -vcodec libx264 -preset faster -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 2200k -b:v 1200k -f mp4 -threads 0 -y  /user_ftp/1037/$i.mp4
```

However, with my 2 pass webm encode and the same code, the video encodes, but no watermark is placed.  Does -vf not work when encoding to webm?

NOT WORKING - VIDEO ENCODES WITH NO WATERMARK:

Webm pass 1

```
ffmpeg -i /youtube/$mediaboxid/$i -codec:v libvpx -quality good -vf 'movie=/media/raid2/uploads/user_ftp/1037/watermarks/w400X224.png [logo];[in][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]' -filter:v scale=400:224 -cpu-used 0 -b:v 500k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate:v 500k -bufsize:v 1000k -threads 0  -an -pass 1 -f webm -y /dev/null
```

Webm pass 2

```
ffmpeg -i /youtube/$mediaboxid/$i -codec:v libvpx -quality good -vf 'movie=/user_ftp/1037/watermarks/w640X360.png [logo];[in][logo] overlay=0:0 [out]' -filter:v scale=640x360 -cpu-used 0 -b:v 500k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate:v 500k -bufsize:v 1000k -threads 0 -an -pass 2 -f webm -y /user_ftp/1037/$i.webm
```

Are there any known issues here with webm specifically?

Comment: Please include the complete console output for the not working command(s). Also, you are applying `-filter` (`-vf` and `-filter:v`) twice and ffmpeg may ignore one.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no special issues with WebM encoding.  As mentioned by LordNeckbeard, your WebM command lines have both a `-vf` option and a `-filter:v` option, but these are the same thing (two different ways to specify the set of filters to apply to the video).  You can use multiple video filters, but specify them using a single `-vf` or `-filter:v` option.

You should use [`-filter_complex`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#filter_005fcomplex_005foption) instead of `-vf` for filtering involving multiple inputs: this is the difference between a [simple](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs) and [complex filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Complex-filtergraphs). It is also easier to make sense of because you can avoid the [`movie`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1) source filter.

If you wanted the [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter to be applied to the result of the [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay,scale=640:-1 ... output
```

If you wanted the `scale` to be applied only to the original input, and not the `overlay` then just switch the location of the filters:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex scale=640:-1,overlay ... output
```

Comment: Problemo solved!!  Thanks very much for your help.  Did not realize that -vf and filter:v were the exact same thing.  Thanks guys for taking the time to answer.